# Haarcascade classifier training

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to create an xml file using samples I took with my camera. This is a test run where I put my camera against my window and let it take a picture every 30 seconds of passing cars for a while. I have now about 200 pictures (just for a small test), but I can't get any further.

I made a selecting tool to pick out the cars on pictures (bounding boxes) and mark pictures as negatives if there aren't any. Here are 2 examples of what the application looks like:

[image]
[image]

The application then saves the marked objects in `positive.txt` file as follows, skipping the non-marked pictures or the pictures marked as negative:

```
/samples/img_0000.jpg 1 74 66 34 30
/samples/img_0001.jpg 2 78 69 31 25 218 129 61 38
/samples/img_0003.jpg 1 83 72 21 21
/samples/img_0005.jpg 1 76 65 19 17
/samples/img_0006.jpg 1 127 112 37 24
/samples/img_0007.jpg 2 83 72 22 21 127 112 36 22
...
```

The negative pictures are simply saved to `negative.txt` file as follows:

```
/samples/img_0002.jpg
/samples/img_0004.jpg
/samples/img_0024.jpg
/samples/img_0026.jpg
...
```

Finally I try to run the haar training algorithm with `/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining -data samples -vec positive.txt -bg negative.txt -npos 99 -nneg 20 -nstages 5 -mem 128 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -nonsym -mode ALL`.

Don't mind the settings, I simply need this to work before I use a much more powerful computer to do the actual training on actual data with much more pictures.

For that I get the following output and error:

```
Data dir name: samples
Vec file name: positive.txt
BG  file name: negative.txt, is a vecfile: no
Num pos: 99
Num neg: 20
Num stages: 5
Num splits: 1 (stump as weak classifier)
Mem: 128 MB
Symmetric: FALSE
Min hit rate: 0.999000
Max false alarm rate: 0.500000
Weight trimming: 0.950000
Equal weights: FALSE
Mode: ALL
Width: 24
Height: 24
Applied boosting algorithm: GAB
Error (valid only for Discrete and Real AdaBoost): misclass
Max number of splits in tree cascade: 0
Min number of positive samples per cluster: 500
Required leaf false alarm rate: 0.03125

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+
|  0|
+---+



Number of features used : 261600

Parent node: NULL

*** 1 cluster ***
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Vec file sample size mismatch) in icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromVec, file /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/haartraining/cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1930
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/haartraining/cvhaartraining.cpp:1930: error: (-2) Vec file sample size mismatch in function icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromVec

Aborted
```

Does anybody know what that means? Why is there an error with sample size, whatever that is... I also tried replacing relative paths with absolute paths, but I got the same error. Is what I'm trying to do actually right, I haven't found any explicit examples on how to create a classifier from existing and marked pictures.

Comment: Hi, Do you can share your positives, negatives and Sheel commands please?
I used the following command: 

rm * .vec 
find ./negatives_images -iname "* jpg"> negatives.txt 

opencv_createsamples -vec puma.vec puma.jpg -img -bg negatives.txt -num 1500 -bgcolor 50 -bgthresh 50 -maxxangle -maxyangle 0 0 0 -maxzangle -w 80 -h 80 

opencv_haartraining -vec puma.vec -bg negatives.txt -npos 1 -nneg 1418 -mem 4096 -w 80 -h 80 -data. 

ls directory: 
negatives.txt puma.jpg negatives_images/

positive http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-H2IZ7yyNjTg/UEZnPmSEwAI/AAAAAAAAAkI/16ZTOTwOKkI/s1600/Logo+da+Puma.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the `.vec` file is not simply the `positive.txt` file, it must be generated using `opencv_createsamples`.

So first I created the `training_24-24.vec` file (which is not just a text file) using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/opencv_createsamples -vec training_24-24.vec -info positive.txt -bg negative.txt -w 24 -h 24 -num 100
```

which created the `training_24-24.vec` file. Compared to my original question I remade the `positive.txt` file with square selections. Then I launched the classifier training with

```
/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining -data samples -vec training_24-24.vec -bg negative.txt -npos 99 -nneg 20 -nstages 5 -mem 128 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -nonsym -mode ALL
```

The performance is simply awful at this point, it recognises everything but the cars. [This article](http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/11/faq-opencv-haartraining/) says that one should use something like 1000 positive and 2000 negative images to start having something acceptable. Also it says for the `-nstages` option:

> It’s useless to set many stage, if you have small number of positive, negative samples